# How to center ngb-pagination in angular4?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

```
<div class="col-12 text-center">
  <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="120" [(page)]="pageNumber" 
   [maxSize]="5" [rotate]="true" [boundaryLinks]="true" size="lg">
  </ngb-pagination>
</div>
```

I am using ng-bootstrap and angular 4 for my project, the above code does not center pagination component.  Is there a way to center it ? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try like this :

**template.html**

```
<div class="col-12 justify-content-center">
  <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="120" [(page)]="pageNumber" 
   [maxSize]="5" [rotate]="true" [boundaryLinks]="true" size="lg">
  </ngb-pagination>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
.justify-content-center {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Now with bootstrap 4 you can just use bootstrap classes

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="120" [(page)]="pageNumber" 
   [maxSize]="5" [rotate]="true" [boundaryLinks]="true" size="lg">
  </ngb-pagination>
</div>
```